# Typo3 with extbase - get translation for specific language

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I wrote a backend hook so that I can write notification E-mails as soon as an item is set to hidden = 0 in typo3. I managed to access LocalizationUtility to access my translation files, like this:

```
$localization = $objectManager->get('\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility');
$localization::translate('tx_extplugin_domain_model_item.email.text1', 'ExtPlugin')
```

But how do I define which language to use? It doesn't seem like the translation function takes a language parameter, so how do I get the text in a different language?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the readLLfile Method to get specific translation by languagekey. This will return a array of all translated strings in $file.

`$fd = GeneralUtility::readLLfile($file, $langKey);`

Comment: oh my god, thank you! This works like a charm! perfect! I called GeneralUtility::readLLFile('EXT:pgk_extensionname/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf', 'en') and I get an array with vfalues!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Typo3 translation in this way - Typo3 will always translate to the *current* language scope.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045839/typo3-translate-to-not-current-language)  I think the only way you could do it would to hold your translations outside of Typo3 (in an array or similar), and then do your own translation, rather than using the Typo3 built in one.

Comment: ok that's too bad. But thank you very much for your answer, at least now I know it's not possible and I can stop trying.